# Setting constant values in constraints depending on actual values of variables

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, integer-programming, logical-constraints

We have a set of constraints in an ILP of the following form :

$ \gamma (X_{11} + X_{12} + X_{13}) \leq C_1$ where $X_{ij} \in \{0,1\}$ and the value of $\gamma$ is going to depend on the actual value of $X_{ij}$ variable being set. For example, if $X_{11} = 1, X_{12} = 1, X_{13} = 1$ then $\gamma = 0.45$, while on the other hand, $X_{11} = 0, X_{12} = 0, X_{13} = 1$ then $\gamma = 0.76$ and so forth. How can such constraints be encoded in an ILP where the constant factor actually depends on the value of the variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given constant $C_1$, you want to enforce
$$\left(X_{11} \land X_{12} \land X_{13}\right) \implies 0.45(1+1+1) \le C_1.$$
Equivalently, you want to enforce the contrapositive
$$0.45(1+1+1) > C_1 \implies \lnot \left(X_{11} \land X_{12} \land X_{13}\right),$$
equivalently,
$$\lnot \left(X_{11} \land X_{12} \land X_{13}\right) \quad \text{if $0.45(1+1+1) > C_1$},$$
which you can enforce with linear constraint
$$(1-X_{11}) + (1-X_{12}) + (1-X_{13}) \ge 1 \quad \text{if $0.45(1+1+1) > C_1$},$$
which simplifies to
$$X_{11} + X_{12} + X_{13} \le 2 \quad \text{if $0.45(1+1+1) > C_1$}. \tag1$$

Similarly,
$$\left(\lnot X_{11} \land \lnot X_{12} \land X_{13}\right) \implies 0.76(0+0+1) \le C_1$$
yields
$$X_{11} + X_{12} + (1-X_{13}) \ge 1 \quad \text{if $0.76(0+0+1) > C_1$}.\tag2$$

Comment: so in essence, we would have to include constraints such as $X_{11}+X_{12}+(1−X_{13})≥1$ if $0.76(0+0+1)>C_1$, for all 2^n combinations if I understand correctly? Also, any reference to how to express the if condition in normal ILP form?

Comment: Yes, $2^n$ in the worst case.  But you impose the constraint only if the condition holds.  Constraints (1) and (2) are already in normal ILP form.

Comment: Or is $C_1$ supposed to be a decision variable rather than an input parameter?

Comment: No, $C_1$ is an input parameter, it is in normal ILP form, thanks for the clarification.